# How to get the macro to run only if it hits a certain filter

Tags: excel, vba

I have a big macro that is doing a lot of copying from a master workbook and 15 daily reports and pasting to the source workbook. The macro is quite big and i will only paste relevant parts.

The source file matches with the master workbook through the following code ( all works fine):

```
 Public OutShVar As Worksheet   
 Public RngConcat As Range   

 Set OutShVar = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SourceSheet")
 Set RngConcat = OutShVar.Range("A:A")  
 Dim loc As Range
 Dim WCell As Range


 Concat = ShVar.Range(tC & i).Value 
 Set loc = RngConcat.Find(Concat) '(not relevant to this question, it's just setting loc to column A in my source file)


  CRV = loc.Offset(0, 2).Value

  'No CRV ID ID
  If loc.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Not Available" Then
  loc.Offset(0, 80) = "Y"
 Else
  loc.Offset(0, 80) = "N"

   'Line items from the masterwork book
  Set WCell = WShRange.Range("FW:FW").Find(CRV, lookat:=xlWhole)
   'a bunch of copy pasting

   loc.Offset(0, 26) = WCell.Offset(0, -177) 'an example
  End if
 End Sub
```

But the problem is here, right now my CRV key in the source file is like this 
CL810681AG5421BPGB-

however, in the master workbook, it's like this

```
column A                 Column B
Obligation Active        CRV Key
NO                       CL810681AG5421BPGB- 
NO                       CL810681AG5421BPGB-
YES                      CL810681AG5421BPGB-
```

As you can see, my code will only match the first line but i want my code to find "YES" first and then if it doesn't find then go to the NO. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you sort the data, such that `YES` appears first? If not, you may need to have two loop's (one for `NO`, one for `YES`) in conjunction with some sort of early exit condition or Boolean flag to indicate whether a match was found for `YES`? Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Put it in a dictionary and check whether or not it exists when you need.

Comment: I think the sorting should help. Let me try and get back to you. And if that doesn't work, i will check the dictionary part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below logic:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test_Date()

    Dim CRV_Key_Yes As String, CRV_Key_No As String
    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long, Line As Long
    Dim Appears As Boolean

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        CRV_Key_Yes = "YES" & "_" & "CL810681AG5421BPGB-"
        CRV_Key_No = "NO" & "_" & "CL810681AG5421BPGB-"

        Appears = False

        For i = 2 To Lastrow

            If .Range("A" & i).Value & "_" & .Range("B" & i).Value = CRV_Key_Yes Then
                Line = i
                Appears = False
                Exit For
            ElseIf .Range("A" & i).Value & "_" & .Range("B" & i).Value = CRV_Key_No And Appears = False Then
                Line = i
                Appears = True
            End If

        Next i

        MsgBox "CRV Key match on line " & Line & "."

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorting seemed to solve the problem but i will try using your logic as well. So if i have a specific set of instructions for when it says yes, i can just write below Appears=False?

Comment: Yes. When is "YES", Appears=False in order to set boolean to it s initial form.